# Application.Current is null, but new Application() still fails?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an unmanaged application which uses a WPF assembly for some of its user interface. Because of this arrangement `Application.Current` is not created automatically. So when the first WPF window is loaded, my code does this:

```
        if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
        {
            new System.Windows.Application();
        }
```

This works the first time and is the approach [I've seen recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8).

But if the user closes the (only) WPF window, and later loads it again, even though `Current == null` again an exception is thrown when the Application ctor is called.

It is clear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) that you can only have one Application per AppDomain - *but why then is Current null and yet I can't create it?*

---

The exception that is thrown is of type `InvalidOperationException` and has the message:

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the
>   same AppDomain.

Its `InnerException` is null.

---

To work around this I have tried to:

- Construct `Application` using `ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose`
- Explicitly call `Current.Shutdown()` when the WPF window is closed

but neither has made any difference.

Is there some other way to manually manage the lifetime of the `Current` object? Or should I instead attempt to create it when the unmanaged application starts, and then rely on it always being set for the lifetime of the process?

Comment: What is the Exception, and any InnerException?

Comment: @rfmodulator good point, I will check & add that...

Comment: @rfmodulator added

Comment: Can you create a small working example? There are may variables such as bitness/apartment threading etc...which may have to be considered.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Probably yes, I will see if I can strip it down. Its a 32bit unmanaged calling application, and there are no threads being manually created.

Comment: I digged into a similar situation and i had to create a new AppDomain for each Application i had to start.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation you linked states the following in its remarks section:

> Only one instance of the Application class can be created per
>   AppDomain, to ensure shared access to a single set of
>   application-scope window, property, and resource data. Consequently,
>   **the parameterless constructor of the Application class detects whether the instance being initialized is the first instance in an
>   AppDomain; if it is not, an InvalidOperationException is thrown.**

The part I highlighted implies that it is not checking if it is the only / single application currently running, but rather that it checks if any another `Application` instance has been initialized before (regardless of whether or not it has been closed yet).

Taking a look at the [source code of the `Application` class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs.html#145) confirms this: The `Application` class internally uses a static flag (`_appCreatedInThisAppDomain`) that is set only once when initializing the first `Application` instance. But apparently this flag is never reset, which prevents you from creating any more `Application` instances within the same AppDomain.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up, I didn't know the internals. So it seems odd to me then that the .Current property gets reset to null...

Comment: Yup, .Current returns _appInstance which is set to null in  DoShutdown().

Answer (score 3):

This is easy in WinForms, not so much in WPF.

Obviously, we don't have an `Application` problem, we have an `AppDomain` problem.

I put a reasonable amount of effort into this, but couldn't get it to behave as I wanted it to, that is to destroy the old then recreate an `AppDomain` on a new `Thread` when the spacebar is pressed, I suppose that makes sense though given the scope.

It's a work around at best, and may not even be an option in your situation.

> Is there some other way to manually manage the lifetime of the `Current`
>   object?

As best I can tell, the simple answer is to just maintain a WPF message loop `Thread` for the life of the program (via `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`), and use the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to display WPF objects as needed.

Here's an example of what I mean, as implemented in a managed console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = CreateThread();

        t.Start();

        bool quit = false;
        while (!quit)
        {
            switch(Console.ReadKey().Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Application.Current.Shutdown());
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        var w = new Window() { Width = 500, Height = 500, Title = "WPF Window" };
                        w.Show();
                    });
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        var d = new Window() { Width = 500, Height = 500, Title = "WPF Dialog" };
                        d.ShowDialog();
                    });
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
                    //// Nope!
                    //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Application.Current.Shutdown());
                    //t = CreateThread();
                    //t.Start();
                    break;
            }
        };
    }

    static Thread CreateThread()
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
            {
                new System.Windows.Application();

                Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
            }

            Application.Current.Run();
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        return t;
    }
}
```

You'll need references to PresentationCore, PresentationFramework and WindowsBase to build this example.

I hope it at least inspires someone.

**EDIT: FYI, this may not work anymore... It worked when I posted it, now two days later it does not. There was a cumulative update for .NET Framework (kb4538122) installed yesterday, but I'm not sure if this was the breaking change or not.**

**EDIT: I updated the code, it now works again.**